# Проблема при перегрузке оператора "-"

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Не пойму как правильно перегрузить оператор "-" для класса массива.
Описание класса:

```
class Vector {
private:
   double *v; //Указатель (начальный адрес одномерного массива)
   int dim; //Размерность
```

Первая перегрузка оператора, для вычитания одного массива из другого (одинакового размера):

```
Vector Vector::operator- (const Vector & L) { //Пергрузка.Вычитание векторов (только одинакового размера!)
Vector result(L.dim);
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) result = v[i] - L.v[i];
    return result;
}
```

Вторя перегрузка, когда от массива отнимается число:

```
Vector Vector::operator-(const double L) { // Перегрузка.Вычитание из вектора числа.
    Vector result(dim);
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) result = v[i] - L;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `result.v[i] = v[i] - L.v[i];`

Comment: И? В чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: result.v[i]  = v[i] - L.v[i];  и для  второй  result.v[i] =  v[i] - L;

Comment: Я подозреваю, что конструктор из типа `int` у вашего класса не объявлен как `explicit`. Это приводит к тому, что такой код как `result = v[i] - L.v[i]` спокойно компилируется, хотя делает совсем не то, что нужно. Возьмите в привычку почаще объявлять конструкторы как `explicit`.

Comment: объявлять конструкторы как explicit всегда, если  не нет необходимости в неявности

Comment: Опишите подробно, в чём состоит "Проблема при перегрузке оператора “-”
". Какие ошибки или нежелательное поведение возникают?